# Is it possible list inside another list through a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, list, file, numpy, vector

I have some questions about how can I read a .txt file and build one list inside other list through this file.

look:

I have this file:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Right now I'm using numpy to read the file:

```
DataIn = numpy.loadtxt('jpegOut.txt')
```

the return is this:

```
print DataIn
[[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]]
```

But I need this:

```
[[1 2 3],
 [4 5 6],
 [7 8 9]]
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you need to use `NumPy`, or are you open to core Python solutions?

Comment: I can use any solutions, whatever. Just need "comma" between the vectors

Comment: lists use commas in their print display, numpy arrays do not.  But that's a superficial difference; just printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.tolist()` to convert a numpy array to python list:

```
numpy.loadtxt('jpegOut.txt').tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `NumPy`:

```
with open('jpegOut.txt', 'r') as f:
    data_in = [[line] for line in f]
```